# Connect a property to a value located in a Module QML file

Tags: qt, qml, connection

I have the following `QML` file calling a view (**CustomView.qml**). This view is a coming from a module named `CustomPages`.

**help.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import CustomPages 1.0
import CustomGraphics 1.0

Item
{
    property string age
    anchors.fill: parent

    CustomView
    {

    }
}
```

Here's the definition of the view, located in the module `CustomPages`:

**CustomView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import CustomGraphics 1.0

Item
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    CustomLabel
    {
        id: ageLabel
        childLabel.text: ""
    }

    CustomLabel
    {
        id: weightLabel
        childLabel.text: ""
    }
}
```

This view is calling graphical elements in order to create a page. These elements are located in another module, named `CustomGraphics`. Here's one:

**CustomLabel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item
{
    property alias childLabel: label

    Label
    {
        id: label
        text: "Custom Label"
        color: "green"
        x: 10
        y: 50
        // many other attributes which customize the Label
    }
}
```

As you may have deduced from all this, the goal is to separate the graphical elements from the data that is going to update them.

I am trying to *connect* my `property string age` (declared in **help.qml**) as a `Q_PROPERTY` (setter, getter, signal which updates the graphical element) to one of my `CustomLabel`'s values.

All of this from the `C++` side.

Why? It would allow me to easily update the values (styles, positions, etc.) of each of my graphical elements without amending the view page in itself. The data update mechanisms would also be separated from them.

**EDIT**: in fact, the `Q_PROPERTY` needed to update the `text` value of my `CustomLabel` is already coded. What I don't know is how to connect the property declared in the **help.qml** file to one specific `CustomLabel` (*ageLabel*), using the corresponding `Q_PROPERTY`.

Example:

```
// help.qml

property string age

// C++ model

Q_PROPERTY(int  age READ age WRITE setAge NOTIFY ageChanged)

// C++ side
// connect property string age to the specific CustomLabel designed for the age value.

// in CustomView.qml
// updates the corresponding CustomLabel (id: ageLabel)
```

**EDIT_2**: here's what I'm currently trying to do.
I added in my **CustomView.qml** the following line:

```
Component.onCompleted: cppCode.connectPriorities(age)
```

Then in `cpp` file:

```
void cpp::connectPriorities(const QVariant &v)
{
    // generic for loop
    // get each variable's name
    // connect it to corresponding CustomLabel
}
```

Comment: Why not simply pass the `age` property of your `help.qml` component to the `CustomLabel` component?

Comment: Because it would make the view dependent from the data. What if I want to use this view elsewhere with another set of data? See **EDIT_2** for what I've come up during this time.

Comment: Well...the question is another: What happens if the data in `help.qml` is changed? Than all your custom views are broken because they interact with another component where you make some assumptions. Please give some more information what you really want to do in `CustomLabel.qml`